# Get content inside brackets using grep

Tags: grep

I have text that looks like this:

```
Name (OneData) [113C188D-5F70-44FE-A709-A07A5289B75D] (MoreData)
```

I want to use `grep` or some other way to get the ID inside `[]`.

How to do it?

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: `grep -oE '[0-9A-F-]{36}' file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this via bash (GNU grep required):

```sh
t="Name (OneData) [113C188D-5F70-44FE-A709-A07A5289B75D] (MoreData)"
echo "$t" | grep -Po "(?<=\[).*(?=\])"
```

The pattern will give you everything between the brackets, and uses a zero-width look-behind assertion `(?<= ...)` to eliminate the opening bracket and uses a zero-width look-ahead assertion `(?= ...)` to eliminate the closing bracket.

The `-P` flag activates perl-style regexes which can be useful not having too much to escape, then. The `-o` flag will give you only the wanted result (not the "non-capturing groups").

If you don't have GNU grep available, you can solve the problem in two steps (there are probably also other solutions):

1. Get the ID with the brackets (`\[.*\]`)
2. Remove the brackets (`]` and `[`, here via *sed*, for example)

```sh
echo "$t" | grep -o "\[.*\]" | sed 's/[][]//g'
```

As [Cyrus commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63620783/get-content-inside-brackets-using-grep/63621013?noredirect=1#comment112503973_63620783), you can also use the pattern `grep -oE '[0-9A-F-]{36}'` if you can ensure not having strings of length 36 or larger containing only the characters `0-9`, `A-F` and `-` and if all the IDs have the length of 36 characters, of course. Then you can simply ignore the brackets.

Comment: I'm getting an error trying to use it ` grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]`

Comment: @LenaBru: This requires GNU grep.

Comment: it gets the middle part, does not remove the square brackets

Comment: it should be `echo "$t" | grep -o "\[.*\]" | sed 's/[][]//g'`